# How to get status code of previous command in Sublime-build "cmd"?

Tags: command-line, bash, sublime-text-3, build

I want to use custom build commands for C source codes in Sublime Text 3.
I am using the following code as sublime-build :

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && konsole -e ''bash -c \"./${file_base_name}; echo 'Process returned $?'; read -p 'Press [ENTER] to exit.'\"''"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Here, the portion `echo 'Process returned $?';` is causing serious problem (i.e. build doesn't run at all!) due to trying access to `$?`.

What is the alternative (or what is the right syntax) to use `$?` here ?

Answer (score 0):

$? in bash shows the exit status of the previous command.

$? is the correct syntax.

In an echo, if you use two '' $? wont execute and it will just echo '$?' instead of the exit status, you need to use "" instead.

The line `echo 'Process returned $?';` should not cause a serious problem because it will just echo out what is between '' and ; just terminates the "line"

You're also not very consistent in your writing.
Arent something like this what you are trying to achieve?

```
"cmd" : ["gcc {$file_name} -o ${file_base_name} && konsole -e 'bash -c \"./${file_base_name}';echo \"Process returned $?\";read -p 'Press [ENTER] to exit.'"],
```

I don't really see what you are trying to achieve with
`'\"''"` at the end

Comment: Your suggestion is fine but what I do badly need is keep the `konsole` window open. Your suggestion exits console window immediately after execution.

Comment: Have you checked if their is a option in the konsole command that lets it continue to be open?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky point is correctly escaping the `$` in `$?`, and all the nested quotes. And this is really a nightmare when you have such deep nesting:

- `cmd` is defined as `"..."`
- within that there is `konsole -e '...'`
- within that there is `bash -c "..."`
- within that there is `echo '...'` and `read '...'`

On top of that, you also need to account for Sublime's escaping rules,
which makes writing this correctly a real nightmare,
and impossible in a readable way.

Rather than trying to fix that,
I recommend to extract the complex command into a script that takes `$file_name` and `$file_base_name` as parameters, like this:

```
"cmd" : ["/path/to/build.sh '$file_name' '$file_base_name'"],
```

Then, you can write `/path/to/build.sh` as any shell script,
free of Sublime's parsing rules,
and easy to test independently.